# Trouble understanding AWS storage for Bitnami ownCloud instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I launched an ownCloud instance using a Bitnami image from here

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B0093DDSFE

on clicking through the "Continue" button, you see the next screen shown it the screen shot, where I selected a launched an m1.small instance with 160GB of storage

https://i.stack.imgur.com/87aDY.jpg

But when I go into the AWS console and look at the machine, I see that it only has one volume which is only 10GB.  But if I ssh into the machine, and run

```
df -h


Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  3.6G  5.7G  39% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            815M   12K  815M   1% /dev
tmpfs           166M  196K  165M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            826M     0  826M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       147G   60M  140G   1% /mnt
```

I see the roughly 140G drive on /dev/xvdb.  I guess the question I'm trying to answer is, where does this storage correspond to in the AWS console?  How am I paying for it, is it a fixed price each month?  Is it possible to get more storage in the future?  I've been trying to research this on my own but hoping someone could provide a more authoritative answer and some docs to look at.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little confusingly laid out in that screenshot, but `m1.small` instances have a 160GB [instance store drive](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) available *in addition to* their main EBS volumes.

Its contents are not persistent - any data on it goes away if the instance is stopped or terminated. As such, it's best used for temporary storage, swap, stuff you don't care about, etc.

You don't pay storage costs for it, and its size is fixed for a particular instance type - you can't provision more of them for an instance like you can with EBS volumes.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your input.  I believe you are right, I have been reading up on this.  If so, it's really kind of misleading to have this "one-click install" of ownCloud, only to find out that the disk it's using to store your files on is temporal.  I guess I need to custom configure a machine that uses only EBS (100GB+) to do something like this?